# Convert a generic string array into a string litteral union in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am working on a module where I want to let users define a list of "allowable types", to be used in other methods, but I'm struggling to make this work properly with typescript:

```js
function initSomething<T extends ArrayLike<string>>(eventTypes:T) {
  type EventType = T[number];
  
  function doTheThing(type:EventType) {
    console.log(type, eventTypes);
  }
  
  return { doTheThing, eventTypes };
}

// I'd like this to throw an error: 'potato' is not one of ['hello', 'bye']
initSomething(['hello', 'bye']).doTheThing('potato');
```

I know the trick that casts an array of strings into a const to convert it into a string litteral union type:

```js
const eventTypes = ['hello', 'bye'] as const
type EventType = typeof eventTypes[number]
```

but I can't figure out how to adapt this to my case, where the array is a generic

I have managed to make something work, but it seems weird: I use `keyof` to make `T` a map of <eventType, any>.

```js
function initSomething<T>(eventTypes:(keyof T)[]) {
  type EventType = keyof T;

  function doTheThing(type:EventType) {
    console.log(type, eventTypes);
  }
  
  return { doTheThing, eventTypes };
}

// Getting the error below, as expected. Perfect!
// Argument of type '"potato"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "bye"'.
initSomething(['hello', 'bye']).doTheThing('potato');
```

Is there a way to do the same thing without this weird `keyof` trick, and making a simple union of string literals from the array instead ?

Comment: The simplest approach is to make your function generic in what you're calling `ElementType` and not the whole array, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEj7gN).  If you really need to keep it the same you could us a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0OYxN).  Do either of those work for you?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why your solution works and mine doesn't, but... yours works, and is pretty readable too! Would you like to put this in an answer so that I mark it as resolved, or do you want me to do it ? (I've made a [slightly modified version of your example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMMoGU4FsCmUAWKA5gDwCiAbjmFACoCeADjojgB5TUAmAzoj1ABOxAHwAKHFRoNmPAFyJK1OkxwBtALoBKRAG8AUIiOJQkWAkRc4tfDhvExUVQqXTVOg8a+IICHnAAbHAA6ALgiR1UAGlYpFVktAG5DYwBfFKNBPBBBJF1La1t7MCIYyWUZHD5U5PSUNExcAgc1AHJbALDWmNaAI3ocVu1gqxs7QhKxVsY4KABDKDhWpKA))

Comment: I'll write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that TypeScript generally infers that an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `['hello', 'bye']` has the type `string[]`.  Often that's the type people want, such as in this code:

```
const arr = ['hello', 'bye'];
//    ^? const arr: string[]
arr.push('howdy'); // okay
```

It would be pretty annoying if every time you initialized a string array the compiler assumed that it could only contain the exact [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) values you put into it, in their exact order.  But sometimes you *do* want the compiler to assume that, such as in your case (well, at least the literal values, if not the order).

---

As you noticed, you could use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (the term "cast" is discouraged here) to get that behavior:

```
const arr = ['hello', 'bye'] as const;
// const arr: readonly ["hello", "bye"]
arr.push("howdy"); // error
```

and indeed you can use that with your version of `initSomething()`:

```
initSomething(['hello', 'bye'] as const).doTheThing('potato'); // error
// -----------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"potato"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "bye"'.
```

But you might not want the caller to need to remember to do that.

---

One approach is to use a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) in your function, like this:

```
function initSomething<const EventTypes extends ArrayLike<string>>(eventTypes: EventTypes) {
    //                 ^^^^^
    type EventType = EventTypes[number];

    function doTheThing(type: EventType) {
        console.log(type, eventTypes);
    }

    return { doTheThing, eventTypes };
}
```

This tells the compiler to infer `EventTypes` more or less as if the caller had specified `as const`.  You can see that it works as expected:

```
initSomething(['hello', 'bye']).doTheThing('potato');
// --------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"potato"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "bye"'.
```

---

Still, at least with this example, you might not need this complexity.  It doesn't seem like you really care about the `EventTypes` type parameter, just the `EventType` you compute from it.  In this case you might as well make your function generic in `EventType` directly:

```
function initSomething<EventType extends string>(eventTypes: ArrayLike<EventType>) {
    function doTheThing(type: EventType) {
        console.log(type, eventTypes);
    }
    return { doTheThing, eventTypes };
}
initSomething(['hello', 'bye']).doTheThing('potato');
// --------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"potato"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"hello" | "bye"'.
```

That works because when a type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`, the compiler assumes that you care about its string literal type (or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types).  That is, `extends string` gives the compiler a *context* in which literal types will be preserved.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcgBYFMA2+ImANDJgEYCeumAugNwBQA9CzBzAHoD8MokWIgQAuGNAQBLMAHN0dJsIB0ABwCuEbAAocIAO4ATKpgCUDGGxggA1nCpMmA6PCQAmVBhwEipctVp08BD84NDMlk5CbmIIuHAG4PhUGABEeIQgKWQp-ikKwq6qGtpp+kYpZhbsuEggCA5gcAC2uBAqcMC4MADyUjIwAN5MnDAAZmpgwFCS4DDSklAAyiAtUNjSMgA8ACowuAAeULhgBsEAgkh2ADKS1ribEhsAfE9auABux1DbVCqtYtsTINhiNOFBfl0AKKfMDfCEebboMBqJoUGqMBygzjjSbTWYJbZ4QkbLTgv5iaFfH5-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-4NPvR97gyv4nn-XDNzxKUxLQ7Mf0KqrcM4fCWTZdDcBYkC+VkoU4I4GjJWlermL2LCLw4jUtR4lK0IEjIhP8ehRMY1CSUkl1pNMfqqhgJTDoUlTVMTEZLBTNMdI7PS-m7QzMmM0yhAsqsazrOymxbNtnP0nsMhSAch1yTAx2FIA)